# Wrong hexadecimal representation in the memory view of eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, memory

In eclipse (2012-12) I inspected the memory of an int-array in unsigned integer and hexadecimal.

The int-array is defined as:

```
int Karray[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,255,258,18};
```

The memory view representing unsigned int is:
[image: The starting point in memory is highlighted in blue]

On the other hand, if I switch to hexadecimal representation then I got the following result:
[image: Represenation flipped for 258 corresponding to 0x102 at address 0061FF10]

The starting point in memory is also highlighted in blue. For all values despite of 258 it seems that the most-significant position is on the right and the least-significant position is on the left. But for the value of 258, it is represented in the memory by 201, thus it seems that the most-significant position is on the right and the least-significant position on the left.

Could someone can give me a hint to solve this contradiction?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a eclipse release that is nearly 10 years old?

Comment: The memory view shows the value as `0x02010000` which is simply `0x00000102` in little endian byte order

Comment: You say "it seems that the most-significant position is on the right and the least-significant position on the left" about both cases. Where's the contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

The hexadecimal view is just showing the bytes in memory without trying to convert them to integers.

On your processor integer values are stored in memory in ["Little Endian"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) format. This means that the least signifcant **byte** is stored at the lowest memory address.

So when loading the `02010000` bytes as an integer the value is constructed like this:

```
0x00 << 24 | 0x00 << 16 | 0x01 << 8 | 0x02
```

which is 258.